# Entity Frameworks queries remain active and prevent application to close

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I have a vb.net application that use EF 6 with SQL server 2008R2.
When the application is open , the first form is a Login form , and after the Main form is open. On application properties I've configured : Shutdown Mode - when last form closes.
On every form of my application I have several EF Queries that run , some of them runs when the form is open , some runs on demand by pressing buttons.
Now , when I close my Main form , the form closes but the application does not finish but continue to run.
I've tested and I've found that when the form is closing Application.OpenForms.Count is 1. So as I've configured this is the last form and closing this should close the application but this is not happening.
So when the Mainform is closing , the application continue to run. I've paused the application at this point , and on Thread list I've found all the EF Queries that are already executed on Main form. It seems that these queries remain active , and I don't know the reason why ?
The context is declared locally on Main form , and also I've tried to do context.dispose on form's closing event , but the problem is the same.
All the queries that I run as like this for example :

```
MyobjBindingSource.DataSource = (From t In context.myobjs Where t.art = art1
                                 Select t).ToList
```

If I open other forms , work and after close these forms , when I try to close the main form , the application continue to run , and on the thread list there are all the queries that are executed from all the forms that I've open before. so more forms are open , more queries remain in thread list even when those forms are closed.

These are some screenshoot of threads windows when I pause my application after I have closed the main form :

[threads1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTsnx.jpg)

[threads2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7jzA.jpg)

What can I do ?

**Update :**
I've tried to run my application from running directly the .exe file on /bin/debug folder. ( i'm running windows 10 ).
When the application is open , on task manager there's only 1 entry for my application under Apps section .
When I close my application , this icon on Apps section is removed , but an icon is added under Background processes , and this is never removed.
But on my application  I have not start any other thread through my code.
What this can be ?
Thank you !.

Comment: show us your code